# Interceptação e redirecionamento

Tags: php, php-7

Minha estrutura

```
localhost/sistema
localhost/sistema/.htaccess
localhost/sistema/site/index.php
```

**Objetivo**: Ao acessar qualquer `url` dentro do `domínio` ocorrer a `interceptação` e o `redirecionamento` à página `index.php` que está no diretório *localhost/sistema/site*

**tentativa no .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -t [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.$ site/index.php [NC,L]
```

**Resultado**.

```
Erro 500
```

Onde estou errando?

**Observação**:

Linha

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

descomentada no **httpd.conf**

e,

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24/htdocs"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Erro do log do Apache:

```
htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Porém, o .`so` está na pasta

Comment: O que a linha `RewriteRule ^.$ - [NC,L]` faz?

Comment: pega as requisições da raíz

Answer (score 0):

uso algo mais simples , funciona para o que eu preciso aqui , testa ai

```
RewriteEngine On
# pasta base de referencia
RewriteBase /app
# Proteje pastas de serem acessadas diretamente
RewriteRule ^(classes|includes|logs) - [F,L]
# arquivo que pode abrir diretamente
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(homologa.*.php)$
# qualquer outro arquivo e redirecionado para o index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Entõ, só de eu colocar RewriteEngine On já dá o erro 500

Comment: você talvez não tenha compilado o apache com o modulo rewrite , se tiver acesso ao prompt digite o comando:
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep rewrite_module 
, verifica se aparece o modulo do rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Embora tenha sido uma solução que eu não aprove. Mas o que há de se fazer.

Deve haver um recurso à isso. Mas saberemos em breve.

A solução é:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    #Require all alowed
</Directory>
```

Ou seja, alterar para todo o `Apache` e não apenas para o `localhost` como a linha abaixo sugere

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24/htdocs"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```